# python array processing: how to generate new values on pixel by pixel basis

Tags: python, arrays, raster

My problem is about array manipulation in python. Want I want to do is to analyze a multiband raster with python and output another raster depending on the results. 
Real case example: I have a raster with 3 bands and I want to see if the different band values for the same pixel are in increasing or decreasing order (from band 1 to band 3). If the values are in increasing order, a new value, lets say "1" will be assigned to that particular pixel in a new output raster (or can be also a new band in the same raster). If the values are in decreasing order, the value "2" will be assigned. I have defined the functions and read the array values but I m stuck at recursively build lists for every pixels, and assign new values for a new raster.

I will post the code that I have until now:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

arcpy.env.workspace = r"\\workspace"

def decrease(A):
    return all(A[i] >= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A)-1)) # function to check if a list has decreasing values
def increase(A):
    return all(A[i] <= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A)-1))  # function to check if a list has increasing values
def no0(A,val):
    return[value for value in A if value !=val]   # function to check if a list has 0 values, and if so, strip them

myArray = arcpy.RasterToNumpyArray(r"raster_3bands.img")  # my 3 bands raster

print myArray.shape  # to see how many dimensions the array has
for z in range(3): # where z is the number of bands, in my case 3
    for y in range(6): #the number of columns, i.e. the vertical axis, in my case 6
        for x in range(6): #the number of rows,i.e. the horizontal axis, in my case 6.
            a = myArray[z,y,x] # get all the values for the 3 bands
            print "The value for axes:  ", z,y,x, " is: ",a
```

What I am missing: 
1. the way to build for every pixel a list which will store the three correspondent band values, so that I can later run the Decrease and Increase functions on those lists 
2. a way to assign new values, pixel by pixel and to store that array as a new raster.

Many thanks for your patience to read this,

Bogdan

So, here is the code for a 3 bands raster:

```
import arcpy, os
import numpy as np
myArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(r"\\nas2\home\bpalade\Downloads\test.img")
nbands = 3

print "Array dimensions are: ", myArray.shape
print "\n"
print "The array is: "
print "\n"
print myArray


increasing_pixels = np.product([(myArray[i] <= myArray[i+1]) for i in range(nbands-1)],axis=0)
decreasing_pixels = np.product([(myArray[i] >= myArray[i+1]) for i in range(nbands-1)],axis=0)

new_band = np.zeros_like(myArray[0])

new_band[increasing_pixels] = 1
new_band[decreasing_pixels] = 2

print "\n"
print "The new array is: "
print "\n"
print new_band
```

The result is attached as jpeg

I do not see the jpeg, so I copy/paste from my results window:

```
Array dimensions are:  (3L, 4L, 4L)


The array is: 


[[[60 62 62 60]
  [64 64 63 60]
  [62 62 58 55]
  [59 57 54 50]]

 [[53 55 55 55]
  [57 57 56 55]
  [55 55 51 50]
  [52 50 47 45]]

 [[35 37 37 36]
  [39 39 38 36]
  [37 37 33 31]
  [34 32 29 26]]]


The new array is: 


[[1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
>>>
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first think to think about here is the structure of the code. When using numpy (and especially in a case like this) it is rare that you need to apply loops. You can simply apply vectorized operations along the axes.

In this case you can use array broadcasting to find which sets of pixels are increasing and decreasing.

```
increasing_pixels = (myArray[0] <= myArray[1]) * (myArray[1] <= myArray[2])
```

This will give you a boolean array where `True` pixels are those which increase across the three bands. The same can be done with decreasing pixels (this time `True` implies pixels that decrease across the band):

```
decreasing_pixels = (myArray[0] >= myArray[1]) * (myArray[1] >= myArray[2])
```

These arrays can act as a mask for your raster, allowing you to identify the pixels that you wish to change value. Below is an example of creating a new band based on the increasing or decreasing values of pixels across the original three bands.

```
new_band = np.zeros_like(myArray[0])

new_band[increasing_pixels==True] = 1
new_band[decreasing_pixels==True] = 2
```

**EDIT:**

For an arbitrary number of bands, the above comparisons can be replaced by:

```
increasing_pixels = np.product([(myArray[i] <= myArray[i+1]) for i in range(nbands-1)],axis=0)
decreasing_pixels = np.product([(myArray[i] >= myArray[i+1]) for i in range(nbands-1)],axis=0)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it is a much better approach! One more question: If I would have a raster with more bands, not just three, how would I loop through n bands to calculate for example increasing_pixels ? I tried to integrate myArray in my increase() function but I get errors...

Comment: Thank you very much again. However, I get different results by substituting `increasing_pixels = (myArray[0] < myArray[1]) * (myArray[1] < myArray[2])` with `increasing_pixels = np.product([(myArray[i] < myArray[i+1]) for i in range(nbands-1)],axis=0)` where nbands is 3. The correct solution is given always by the first statement. The second statement (the one that loops) is giving an incorrect result. I have the same trend over the entire array, i.e. at all positions, the pixels have decreasing values. The second statement gives mixed values (1,2 and 0) where only "2" should exist.

Comment: I m afraid this cannot be the solution because I have different values across the bands (there is no case where one band is equal to another band)...anyway I tried with >= and <= and I got the same result like with > and <, like expected.

Comment: Sorry to come back again, but I have missed something. is it possible, in this approach to skip the 0 values? I mean if band1 == 1, band2 == 0 and band3 == 3, I would still want to have a True value for increasing_pixels.

Comment: You could change the expression in the loop version to read `increasing_pixels = np.product([((myArray[i] <= myArray[i+1]) | (myArray[i+1] == 0)) for i in range(nbands-1)],axis=0)`

Comment: That is excellent, but my goal is to remove all the zeros from these calculations indistinctively of where they appear (in the code above it removes 0 starting with band2). For example, I could have band1 == 0, band2 ==0, band3 == 8, band4 == 0 and band5 == 6. I would like this sequence to be in decreasing order (so the 0 values would not count). I m sorry for this mess and occupying so much of your time.

Comment: This is a more complicated question. It would be better to post this as a new question with a small example that shows the problem. Generally long comment threads like these are frowned upon on stack overflow.